# sub query inside mysql check value from main table gives error of undefine veriable

Tags: mysql

my query is like below

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM`punit_master` `a`

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT *
      FROM 
    (
        SELECT *
          FROM _map_contacts  as t
          LEFT JOIN  contact_master as c on c.contact_id = t.contact_id
          where t.punit_id =a.punit_id
        limit 1

    ) tm LEFT JOIN  contactdetail_master cd ON cd.contactdetail_id = tm.contactdetail_id
) b ON b.agreement_id = a.curr_tenant_agreement_id
```

it gives me error of a.punit_id is undefine

how can I use mail table value in left join inside sub query

Comment: You can't write a *"correlated"* JOIN unless you use MySQL 8.0.14+ with [Lateral](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html), which at first seight seams what you are trying to do here..

Comment: But in general, See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please post table structures and elaborate question in details.

Comment: Also this question  feels like a [first record per "group"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+first+record+per+group) question, so most likely this question is a duplication..

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
     * 
    FROM `punit_master` `a`
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT *
                FROM _map_contacts  as t
                LEFT JOIN  contact_master as c 
                ON c.contact_id = t.contact_id
        ) tm 
        LEFT JOIN  contactdetail_master cd 
        ON cd.contactdetail_id = tm.contactdetail_id
    ) b 
    ON b.agreement_id = a.curr_tenant_agreement_id and a.punit_id = b.punit_id
```

Try this! :)

Comment: hi, thanks, but it will not solve my problem , bcz this sub query gives me 3 result from that required only first record only

Comment: I think that 'where t.punit_id =a.punit_id' is not working bcs mysql hasn't a single value putted on a.punit_id, has the entire table! He get the punit_master table and after get the table b where it will try the join... I really want to help you but I have to know what field you need, and where are allocated...